# Is it possible to read multiple buttons with the CD74HC4067?

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, multiplexer, demultiplex

[image: This is the image of the schematic for the project I am working on]I am working on a project with a claw machine. I am working on this chip (CD4067BE which is equivalent to the CD74HC4067) and I was wondering: can I read more than one button with the CD4067? I tried the following code, and it works great, but when I want to push two buttons, it will not read both of them as zero. Why am I using a chip with the buttons? It was to reduce I/O pins on my PCB for the claw machine. Yes, I could use a matrix, but I want control over my components, whether to turn it on or off. Also, the CD4067 includes all my buttons. I have thirteen buttons. (13 buttons). By the way, this chip is a multiplexer/demultiplexer. I am using this chip as a multiplexer. Oh, and also, I have an Arduino Mega 2560 rev3. I have followed the instructions of [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/278321/reducing-the-number-of-pins-needed-to-read-a-12-key-keypad-where-the-buttons-are), but this doesn't answer if the chip can read more than button at one time. Thanks,

Austin

```
//Mux control pins
int s0 = 5;
int s1 = 4;
int s2 = 3;
int s3 = 2;


//Mux in "SIG" pin
int SIG_pin = 6;

void setup() {
  
  pinMode(s0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(s1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(s2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(s3, OUTPUT);
  
  pinMode(SIG_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  //Loop through and read all 16 values
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i ++) {
    Serial.print("Value at channel ");
    Serial.print(i); 
    Serial.print("is : ");
    Serial.println(readMux(i));
    delay(1000);
  }
}

int readMux(int channel) {
  int controlPin[] =       {s0, s1, s2, s3};
  int muxChannel[16][4] = { {0, 0, 0, 0},
                            {1, 0, 0, 0},
                            {0, 1, 0, 0},
                            {1, 1, 0, 0},
                            {0, 0, 1, 0},
                            {1, 0, 1, 0},
                            {0, 1, 1, 0},
                            {1, 1, 1, 0},
                            {0, 0, 0, 1},
                            {1, 0, 0, 1},
                            {0, 1, 0, 1},
                            {1, 1, 0, 1},
                            {0, 0, 1, 1},
                            {1, 0, 1, 1},
                            {0, 1, 1, 1},
                            {1, 1, 1, 1}
                          };
  //loop through the 4 sig
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
    digitalWrite(controlPin[i], muxChannel[channel][i]);
  }
  //read the value at the SIG pin
  int val = digitalRead(SIG_pin); //return the value
  return val;
}
```

Comment: There is no reason why it can't be used as you want. You're not reading two buttons at once, you're only ever reading one button, the other buttons are ignored. However you should have a pullup on *every* button, not just the Arduino's IO pin.

Comment: Why do the buttons need a pullup resistor? How do I go about reading more than one button at one time?

Comment: The buttons that aren't being read at any one moment will be floating. You need pullups. You don't read more than one button at one time. You only ever read one button. There is only ever one button - the button that is currently selected. All other buttons do not exist.

Comment: If you cycle through the mux's inputs it'll read whatever is there--you're only reading one button at a time, but if it's quick enough, it won't matter. You'll sometimes see circuits w/ a mux that include an aggregated interrupt indicating the processor should read from the mux.

Comment: Is it possible to use LEDs instead of pullup resistors? I read about that on this tutorial: https://www.baldengineer.com/arduino-keyboard-matrix-tutorial.html

Comment: So, this "floating", is it the same as "ghosting" from that tutorial?

Comment: `floating` refers to an input that has a high impedance (resistance) to both ground and supply ... ambient electric charges can randomly push the input to one of the two states ........ `ghosting` happens in some matrix keypads, where a non-pressed key is detected as being pressed because of two, or more, other keys are pressed ... this is the result of the design of the keypad

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an issue to have floating pins on Analog MUX. Maybe some day I'll test if there is higher current draw if left unconnected, but it's not switching anything between two states (and in CMOS switching needs current), so one pull up on the muxed side might be enough. Maybe with bigger line capacitance it might get some false presses when switched to level near gnd?

Comment: Yeah, I am not so sure what floating means and I still don't get the difference.

Comment: Okay, so, I'll put the pullup resistors on. But, what I want to know is how do I read multiple buttons on the chip all at once?

Comment: You don't--you read them one at a time; that's what thismux does--turns *n* signals into one signal, which you select with S0-S3. Again--if you read them sequentially, with little or no delay, it's unlikely to matter--computers fast, humans slow.

Comment: Okay, so, maybe I should switch to the matrix, considering that when I read the data, even fast, it won't work for what I am doing. So, basically, I am trying to use a joystick and some other buttons to run with stepper motors (to control them) on my claw machine. But, the problem is that when I would use a button, it would scan it individually. So, the buttons would not be "smooth," the stepper would have to wait until it gets to a certain channel. It would be a bumpy ride, in other words.

Comment: I think you're over-estimating human perceptive ability, or under-estimating computer speed.

Comment: OT: Your function `readMux()` will be more efficient and faster if you define the constant arrays as such: `static const int controlPin[] = /*...*/;` and `static const int muxChannel[] = /*...*/;`. Currently these variables are allocated on the stack and initialized each time you call the function.

Comment: I think that you are misunderstanding the concept of a multiplexer. Its purpose is to allow multiple signals to share one signal. Therefore you can only read one at a time. If you want to read them simultaneously, you will need an input/output expander. This will allow you to sample all the signals simultaneously on command, then send the data either serially or parallely to the MCU.

Comment: Yeah, but I was just experimenting with this new chip based on that question from Electrical Engineering. I think a matrix will work well for my new PCB design.

Comment: Although, I do want to thank everyone for helping me. I know understand that the concept of the mux is to read with a single output/input. So, it HAS to read it one at a time, because I don't want extra hardware. It's been fun. I will post the link to the tutorial for my claw machine on the Arduino Forum at arduino.cc in the upcoming future. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way to write to the 4-bit MUX select pins is to use shifting and masking, something like this:

```cpp
// MUX control pins
byte s0 = 2;
byte s1 = 3;
byte s2 = 4;
byte s3 = 5;
byte controlPin[] = { s0, s1, s2, s3 };

. . .

byte readMux(byte channel)
{
  // Loop through the 4 signals
  for (byte b = 0; b < 4; b++, channel >>= 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(controlPin[b], channel & 1);
  }
  // Read and return the value at the SIG pin
  return digitalRead(SIG_pin);
}
```